# Why is necessary for finding strongly connected components to have a reverse graph?

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to learn SSC, but it is illogical to me why I need a reverse graph for it. I drew a graph and it's reverse:

[image: A graph and its reverse]

So, we have a road from vertice 6 to vertice 5, and we have a road from vertice 5 to vertice 6. In the reverse graph we have road from 5 to 6, but if I delete vertice 8 we still have road from 6 to 5 in the original graph, but no road from 5 to 6, but in the reverse graph we have a road from 5 to 6, so this means that we have SSC ( 5 6 ), but this is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by having SCC(5 6) ?

Comment: Like having subgraph 5-6 SSC

Comment: Please take note of the definition of strongly connected components, since it requires that every pair of vertex in the component must be mutually reachable. So if $u$ is reachable from $v$, but not the other way around then they cannot be part of the same SCC.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.